# Can UIPasteBoard be accessed from Safari?

Tags: iphone, uipasteboard

I'd like to copy something from a native application into the paste board. And then read the copied value from the native browser. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean read it from the pasteboard without having the user actually paste it? If so, then  the answer is a definite **no** -- reading the pasteboard without user input would be a security no-no (suppose you'd just copied your credit card # or SS# in another app?).

Comment: I mean writing to a system based named UIPasteBoard from an application and reading it from the browser.

Comment: If you provide a text input form within the browser, the user should be able to paste it in via the usual cut-and-paste mechanisms. Otherwise, no dice -- the browser cannot access the system pasteboard itself.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was interested in doing - accessing the system pasteboard from the browser. Its a shame that it is not possible.. there are obvious reasons why it would be useful.